# how to restrict special character except space in a table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

i have a requirement to insert data into a varchar2 column.can anyone please help me how to restrict special characters except space in a table field in oracle and also the field should not accept two consecutive space

Comment: add a check constraint for the column

Comment: You want to clean the data or you want to prevent access of undesired data and fail the insert?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question.

Comment: To explain Dudu's question: Say a value does include "special characters". Do you need to remove the special characters and insert what's left in the target table? Or is the requirement that such values shouldn't be inserted at all - ONLY insert the values that didn't have any special characters in them? For example, let's say ^ is a special character, and you have the value ab^x. Do you insert abx, or do you not insert anything for this value (because it had special characters)? Also: WHAT IS A SPECIAL CHARACTER? Is - a special character (as in Jo-Ann)? Is the comma , a special character?

Comment: Or - as Gordon is guessing - is this a new table, you don't have any existing data that you need to insert, and your question is simply how to restrict what will be inserted in that column in the future?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for a check constraint, which seems to need regular expressions.  Something like this:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_col
    check (regexp_like(col, '^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$') and col not like '%  %');
```

I'm not sure what the set of characters is, but the above is for alphanumeric and space.

Note:  You can create the regular expression to preclude the double spaces.  I find the above easier to follow.

Comment: Yes.  I just think this is easier to understand.

Comment: can u plz help me solving this without using like operator

Comment: @ManoranjanSamal . . . Please explain why you don't want to use the `like` operator.